# Adding whitespace handling to existing Java regex

Tags: java, regex, string, removing-whitespace

A long time ago I wrote a method called `detectBadChars(String)` that inspects the String argument for instances of so-called "bad" characters.

The original list of bad characters was:

- '~'
- '#'
- '@'
- '*'
- '+'
- '%'

My method, which works great, is:

```
// Detects for the existence of bad chars in a string and returns the
// bad chars that were found.
protected String detectBadChars(String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[~#@*+%]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    StringBuilder violatorsBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if(matcher.find()) {
        String group = matcher.group();
        if (!violatorsBuilder.toString().contains(group))
            violatorsBuilder.append(group);
    }

    return violatorsBuilder.toString();
}
```

The business logic has now changed, and the following are now **also** considered to be bad:

- Carriage returns (`\r`)
- New lines (`\n`)
- Tabs (`\t`)
- Any consecutive whitespaces (`"  "`, `"    "`, etc.)

So I am trying to modify the regex to accomodate the new bad characters. Changing the regex to:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[~#@*+%\n\t\r[ ]+]");
```

...throws exceptions. My thinking was that adding "\n\t\r" to the regex would allot for newlines, tabs and CRs respectively. And then adding `"[ ]+"` adds a new "class/group" consisting of whitespaces, and then quantitfies that group as allowing 1+ of those whitespaces, effectively taking care of consecutive whitespaces.

Where am I going awyre and what should my regex be (and why)? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just using `\\s` will account for all of them. And add the `+` quantifier on entire character class, to match 1 or more repetition:

```
Pattern.compile("[~#@*+%\\s]+");
```

Note that in Java, you need to escape the backslashes. So it's `\\s` and not `\s`.

Comment: Argh! for 2 seconds! (+1)

Comment: +1 also note that the exception is thrown because you need to escape the backslashes themselves.

Comment: You're just forbidding all whitespace.  The way I read it, `\r`, \n` and `\t` are always forbidden, but a simple space character is okay--it's just two or more *consecutive* spaces that aren't allowed.

Comment: @AlanMoore. I see that OP was doing `[ ]+` to match 1 or more whitespace. So, may be he meant that only, just that he didn't put it up in words correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should work.

```
Pattern.compile("[~#@*+%\n\t\r\\s{2,}]");
```

You need \\s{2,} to match any consecutive whitespaces.

**Edit:** I did a mistake above. Thanks to Alan Moore for pointing it out. Here is the new solution.

```
Pattern.compile("[~#@*+%\n\t\r]|\\s{2,}")
```

Comment: Inside a character class, `{2,}` is not a quantifier meaning *two or more*, it's just a list of literal characters: `{`, `2`, `,`, or `}`.